# ejecutar trigger affter insertar datos en tabla y actualice campo en otra dependiendo de una suma

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, trigger

estoy tratando de realizar un trigger que se ejecute cada vez que realice un insert en la tabla TBLPAGOS el cual debe sumar la columna valorPago y compararlo con la suma de los campos interes + capital de la tabla TBLPRESTAMOS y actualizar el campo estado en esta ultima tabla.

tablas

```
     CREATE TABLE `tblpagos` (
          `idPago` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `pagoValor` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `pagoPrestamoId` int(11) NOT NULL
        );


        INSERT INTO tblpagos (idPago, pagoValor, pagoPrestamoId) VALUES
        (1, 25000, 1),
        (2, 10000, 1),
        (1, 25000, 1));

    CREATE TABLE `tblprestamos` (
      `idPrestamo` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `capital` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `interes` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `estado` int(11) NOT NULL
    );


    INSERT INTO tblpagos (idPrestamo, capital, interes,estado) VALUES
    (1, 500000, 50000, 1),
    (2, 200000, 20000, 1));
```

intentando hacer el trigger

```
 DELIMITER $$

        CREATE TRIGGER t_UpdateEstadoPrestamo AFTER INSERT ON tblpagos
          FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
UPDATE tblprestamos SET prestamoEstado=3
 WHERE (SELECT prestamoImporte + prestamoT_Interes = SUM(CASE WHEN pagoPrestamoId = NEW.pagoPrestamoId THEN pagoValor ELSE 0 END) 
    FROM tblprestamo
    LEFT JOIN tblpagos ON idPrestamo=pagoPrestamoId WHERE idPrestamo=NEW.pagoPrestamoId);
        END
        $$
        DELIMITER ;
```

mysql me marca error y no se como crearlo

> Ocurrieron uno o más errores al procesar el pedido: Falló la siguiente
>   consulta: "CREATE TRIGGER `t_UpdateEstadoPrestamo` AFTER INSERT ON
>   `tblpagos` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE tblprestamos SET prestamoEstado=3;
>   WHERE (SELECT prestamoImporte + prestamoT_Interes = SUM(CASE WHEN
>   pagoPrestamoId = NEW.pagoPrestamoId THEN pagoValor ELSE 0 END) FROM
>   tblprestamo LEFT JOIN tblpagos ON idPrestamo=pagoPrestamoId WHERE
>   idPrestamo=NEW.pagoPrestamoId) "
>
> MySQL ha dicho: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'WHERE
>   (SELECT prestamoImporte + prestamoT_Interes = SUM(CASE WHEN
>   pagoPrestamoId' en la linea 2

tambien esoty intentando con este otro codigo y no me deja

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_UpdateEstadoPrestamo1 AFTER INSERT ON tblpagos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    DECLARE totalimporte double;
    DECLARE totalpagos double;
    SET totalimporte = (SELECT p.capital + p.interes from tblprestamos p WHERE idPrestamo=  NEW.pagoPrestamoId);
    SET totalpagos = (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN pagoPrestamoId = NEW.pagoPrestamoId THEN pagoValor ELSE 0 END) from tblpagos);
    IF (totalimporte = totalpagos) THEN
        UPDATE tblprestamo SET prestamoEstado = 3 WHERE idPrestamo=NEW.pagoPrestamoId;
END IF;

END
```

me sale este error

Esta versión de MariaDB no soporta todavia 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

## alguine tiene una idea de como puedo realizar este trigger?

Comment: ya coloque el error por favor en lo que me puedan ayudar o como implementarlo

Comment: El error se debe a que tienes un `;` (_el cual deberías sacar_) justo cuando haces `SET prestamoEstado=3;`.

Comment: le quite el ; de SET prestamoEstado=3 y se lo agregue al final del parentesis WHERE idPrestamo=NEW.pagoPrestamoId); pero me sale este mensaje al insertar datos
Table 'tblprestamo' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Comment: El error es autoexplicativo. El trigger usa tblprestamo dentro del select y actualiza tblprestamo. Eso no está permitido.

Comment: que debo hacer?, nose mucho de trigger como implementar in if o algo asi

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué versión de MariaDB está usando?. Desde la versión 10.2.3 de MariaDB existe soporte para múltiples disparadores (triggers) por tiempo de acción y evento, ver [CREATE TRIGGER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/create-trigger/) (disculpe pero la documentación está en Inglés), sin embargo, en su caso realmente lo que necesita es eliminar el disparador (trigger) `t_UpdateEstadoPrestamo` para poder crear `t_UpdateEstadoPrestamo1`.

Aquí su ejemplo [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=31c1914d2cc5e6cb607bc8a819c3324f) usando el segundo disparador `t_UpdateEstadoPrestamo1`.